# How to align text on baseline in MetaFun without using setMPtext?

Tags: fonts, context, metafont, metafun

I want to draw **several pieces of text** that should be aligned so I need to be able to **place these texts according to their baseline**.

Looking at the MetaFun manual, pages 143-144, it is explained that baseline alignment can be achieved through several methods:

- defining text with `\setMPtext` and calling `draw` on the object returned by `\MPbetex`,
- `draw` the object returned by `textext.origin`,
- `draw` the object returned by `thelabel.origin`.

**However, when I test these three methods with the following code, only the first one works properly.**

```
\starttext
\setMPtext {1} {Foo}
\setMPtext {2} {Bap}

\startMPpage
draw \MPbetex{1} shifted (0,0);
draw \MPbetex{2} shifted (0.5cm,0);

draw textext.origin("Foo") shifted (0,-1cm);
draw textext.origin("Bap") shifted (0.5cm,-1cm);

draw thelabel.origin("Foo",(0,-2cm));
draw thelabel.origin("Bap",(0.5cm,-2cm));
\stopMPpage

\stoptext
```

[image: example result]

Is their a way to **align text on baseline without needing to "pre-declare" all pieces** with `\setMPtext`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The definition of `\MPbetex` essentially reads:

```
\def\MPbetex #1{btex \begincsname\??mptext#1\endcsname\space etex}
```

That is, it just receives the string stored using `\MPtext` and places it between `btex ... etex`.  Of course you can also do that by hand.

```
\startMPpage
draw btex Foo etex shifted (0,0);
draw btex Bap etex shifted (0.5cm,0);
\stopMPpage
```

[image]

Comment: I thought `textext` was the exact equivalent of placing text between `btex..etex`. My bad.

Comment: I have two follow-up questions: how is is possible to insert the value of a MetaPost string variable between `btex..etex`? And why the alignment is different with `textext`?

Comment: @Silverspur To get the value of a variable set with `\setMPtext{1}{...}` between `btex ... etex` use something like `draw btex \MPtext{1} etex;`.  Regarding `textext` I'm not 100% sure but I believe that it is simply a shortcut for `thelabel(btex ... etex)`.

Comment: Ok. I just happened to find on another question that `textext.d(...)` also aligns on baseline.